# probability involving permutation and combination

Tags: probability

question:ten ping-pong balls labelled 1 to 10 are placed in a box.  Two of these balls are then drawnfrom the box.  What is the probability that the label of one ball is even while the label of theother ball is odd if we care about the order of the two balls and no repetitions are allowed

the true answer is 5/9 but my answer is different.
can you please guide me to correct answer

Comment: Please edit to include your computation.

Comment: I assume that your attempted answer is something like "$\frac{5}{10}\cdot\frac{5}{9}$" instead.  That would be the answer to the related but different problem where we very specifically wanted the first ball drawn to be even and the second ball drawn to be odd.  The problem's "true answer" implies that what they are asking for is the probability that the two balls are of opposite parity, either by the first being even and second odd or by having the first ball be odd and the second ball be even.

Comment: I will admit that the phrasing is unfortunately confusing for beginning students... it mentioned it intends for you to think of the order of the balls as being relevant while asking for the probability of an event where order could have been ignored.  It said "*label of* **one** *ball*" which can be incorrectly interpreted as "*label of* **the first** *ball*" rather than "*label of either the first or second ball.*"